# What are safe or average component temperatures for my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, cpu, temperature

My MacBook has been overheating for over a year now. More recently it has begun to perform alarms and automatic shutdowns.

Also on startup there is (a moment) where I see a black screen with source code of some sort before the screen resumes with the grey bootup screen.

Today I have installed Mac Fan Control, and realize that the fan still works on my computer, hopefully I can prevent anymore burning (smell) from the laptop.
Previously I had smcFanControl but it stopped pushing the fan above 2000 so I just thought that my fan didnt work for a long time

I also had my laptop/fan cleaned with air so I dont believe there is any blockage recently.

I have a screenshot showing the current temperatures, I would like to know what temperatures are ideal, safe or average and I will do my best to prolong the life of my laptop by keeping my fans spinning above 2000+ and being more mindful and keeping Activity Monitor open!

[image]

macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)
Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Graphics Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

Comment: During these shutdowns, was the fan spinning up? Have you tried resetting your SMC?

Comment: For what it's worth, Activity Monitor uses a fair amount of CPU whilst open, you should quit it when you're not using it.

Comment: @NoahL yeah right before it shutdown (like 5 seconds) the fan will kick in becoming audible then roaring then shutdown

Comment: @grgarside yeah I notice this too!

Comment: Any reason you have the fan pegged at its minimum speed?

Comment: Also, thermal specs for component parts are always in degrees Celsius.  It would be easier to read if you switched to deg C instead of deg F.

Answer (score 2):

There are two sentences in this question that of concern:

> My MacBook has been overheating for over a year now.

and

> Today I have installed Mac Fan Control, and realize that the fan still
>   works on my computer, hopefully I can prevent anymore burning (smell)
>   from the laptop.

If you are aware that your computer (this is not limited to Apple products) is overheating, it's time to take it in for service.  All modern computers have thermal limits which will shut down the machine if it becomes too hot.  **If this is happening on a regular basis, there is something wrong and it needs to be addressed**

Further, if you actually smell something burning from your computer this is a physical problem that simply cannot be fixed with an app.  This is like running your car without out oil and then expecting to put some high grade gasoline because it has wear additives that prolong the life of your engine in the hopes that it solves the problem.

To put this another way, you can't "un-toast" toast and get bread.

Once you smell the telltale scent of burnt electronics, you're past the point of no return - it's time to take it in for service.

Comment: By service do you mean something like apply thermal paste?

Comment: Perhaps, but given that you were smelling something burning, I would probably check it for damaged components and have them replaced.  Thermal paste at this point is like trying to butter burnt toast....

Comment: should I consider selling it then or take it to Apple store for diagnostics?
Also I performed the reboot Hardware Test last week and it said there were no issues at all...

Comment: (IMO) I would get rid of it.  It's has issues that will only get worse, not better.

Comment: Im just trying to keep it on life-support until I get a job, unless you think it can get money now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't advise you on that without actually seeing the unit and knowing what your budget is.  You may be able to sell it for $3-400 USD and with a few more bucks get a cheap MacBook Pro (2012 or older) that needs some upgrading (like SSD and more RAM)