# For longer periods of use, it is recommended to keep your MacBook Pro 16 inch 2023 closed?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am currently using a desktop Mac that is a few years old. I am interested in buying a new Mac since I have three external monitors. If I get a MacBook, I will mostly use it closed, about 90% of the time or approximately 50 hours per week.

Has anyone had experience using a MacBook closed for such a long time? Could it cause overheating and damage to the graphic card or other components? An alternative for me would be to buy a new Mac desktop computer and a "cheaper" MacBook Pro.

I had a MacBook Pro from 2012 that had problems with the graphic card. It may have been related to using it too much time while closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it cause overheating and damage to the graphic card or other components?

#### This is not an issue

The MacBook line of computers (Air, Pro, etc.) are *designed* to work in [closed clamshell mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/296293/119271) without it being a problem.

Further, CPUs have safeguards to shutdown in the event it excedes it’s thermal limits.

For further reading, see the following posts:

- [Is there such a thing as unsafe cpu levels on mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387534/119271)
- [What are safe or average component temperatures for my MacBook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/287320/119271)
- [Why is it required to have your MacBook Pro plugged-in in closed-clamshell mode with an external display attached?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/296293/119271)
- [Is there a problem with closing the lid of a MacBook Pro when using an external monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243589/119271)

> I had a MacBook Pro from 2012 that had problems with the graphic card. It may have been related to using it too much time while closed.

Bad GPUs and poor BGA work at the manufacturer were the main cause of [GPU failure in 2012 MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/181873/119271) computers